# How to find if selected node is first node of treeview

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I am using a treeview in which I have many parent nodes and child nodes.. in the treeview keydown event I am using the following code to select next node when giving keydown and keyup

```
    Private Sub Treeview1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Treeview1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
            Treeview1.Select()
        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
            Treeview1.Select()
        End If
    End Sub
```

(`Treeview1.Select()`) Now when the selection reaches the very first node, I want to focus previous control of treeview, but I can't check the selected node is first node of treeview. Can anyone help me to find.

Answer (score 5):

You can handle the `AfterSelect` event to find it out

```
Private Sub Treeview1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs)
    If e.Node = Treeview1.Nodes(0) Then
        do something
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How can i check the selected node is first node or last node in afterselect event ..and i can't say the next control focus in after select event... say some other answer

Comment: @GLOIERTECH. I gave you the code how to check the if the selected node is the first node. The first node has index 0, the last node has index Treeview1.Nodes.Count - 1. " i can't say the next control focus in after select event" why not?

Answer (score 0):

You can also check [TreeNode.PrevNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.prevnode.aspx) or [TreeNode.NextNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.nextnode.aspx) of [TreeView.SelectedNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.selectednode.aspx)